# Jackson deserialization of subset of enums

Tags: java, object-oriented, json, serialization

I have several enums that all implement this interface:

```java
public interface SelectOption {
    String getId();
    String getLabel();
}
```

Here's an example:

```java
public enum AuthType implements SelectOption {
    BASIC("basic", "Basic Auth"),
    OAUTH("oauth", "OAuth"),
    TOKEN("token", "Bearer Token");

    private final String id;
    private final String label;

    private AuthType(String id, String label) {
        this.id = id;
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }
}
```

I receive this enum from the API client. First, the client asks for available select options (in this case it's the authentication type), so it needs both the `id` (the one to refer internally and in JSON that goes to the backend) and `label` (the user-friendly name to display in the UI). I want to use a snake case (`bla_bla`) or kebab case (`bla-bla`) notation because I feel it's more natural for any API and so that it does not depend on my java enum constants so that I can rename them as I like. The actual use-case is that the UI will display a drop-down of available authentication methods, the user will pick one and fill out method-specific parameter, i.e. for `BASIC`, that'd be `username` and `password`, for `TOKEN`, that'd be the `token`.

The default deserialization behavior is to match up enum constant names, i.e. `BASIC` string would match with `AuthType#BASIC` automatically. I'm using Jackson for deserialization.

Every time I get an enum that implements `SelectOption` in a serialized form (as a `String`), I get it as `id` that is equal to `SelectOption#getId()`. So, if I supply `basic`, it would error saying something like `"basic" not found in enumeration "AuthType", allowed values are: "BASIC", "OAUTH", "TOKEN"`. And for every other enum, I get it as the enum constant name, so the default deserialization works.

I couldn't create a `JsonDeserializer` for `SelectOption`, because there is a built-in `EnumDeserializer` that takes precedence, so I decided to register a deserializer that works with all enums (registered to `ObjectMapper` for `Enum.class`) and delegates to `EnumDeserializer` if it's not a `SelectOption`.

The following solution works but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it:

```java
public class SelectOptionDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Enum<?>> implements ContextualDeserializer {
    JavaType type;

    public SelectOptionDeserializer() {
    }

    public SelectOptionDeserializer(JavaType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Enum<?> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        if (!SelectOption.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawClass())) {
            EnumDeserializer enumDeserializer = new EnumDeserializer(EnumResolver.constructFor(ctxt.getConfig(), type.getRawClass()), false);
            return (Enum<?>) enumDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        }
        String id = p.getText();
        return (Enum<?>) Stream.of(type.getRawClass().getEnumConstants())
                .map(SelectOption.class::cast)
                .filter(enumConstant -> enumConstant.getId().equals(id))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) {
        return new SelectOptionDeserializer(ctxt.getContextualType() != null
                ? ctxt.getContextualType()
                : property.getMember().getType());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a good reason for having the ids different to the names of the enum values?

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to achieve. Can you please add a bit about that?

Comment: @RobAudenaerde Thanks! I added another paragraph to the description

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks! I added another paragraph to the description that explains the reason

Comment: Actually, your question pushed me to think if my reasoning is good enough. Maybe I should just use the enum constant's name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments, I decided to simply use `Enum#name()` instead of `SelectOption#getId()`. I'm already using a lot of other enums in my JSON responses even though those are simple "type" enums without any extra data like `label` here but nonetheless, I think I was wrong about screaming snake case (`BLA_BLA`) not fitting into APIs, they fit just fine.

Final solution:

```java
public interface SelectOption {
    /**
      * refers to {@link Enum#name()}
      */
    String name();
    String getLabel();
}
```

The actual enum:

```java
public enum AuthType implements SelectOption {
    BASIC("Basic Auth"),
    OAUTH("OAuth"),
    TOKEN("Bearer Token");

    private final String label;

    private AuthType(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }
}
```

This way the default deserialization works as needed, so, no need for a deserializer class.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I'm struggling with the same issue, I have an interface and multiple enums implementing the interface. I found that adding a `name()` method to the interface was not sufficient. What else did you do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: jackson can deserialize enums out of the box. `"BASIC"` would become `AuthType#BASIC`. You don't even need that `name()` method on the interface unless you're using polymorphism somewhere yourself